# Sort only the first 100 lines of a file

Tags: shell, sorting, unix, terminal

I have a text file known as "mywords" that contains this information

```
  A
  A's
  AA's
  AB's
  ABM's
  ...
```

It was has 1000 lines and I would like to sort only the first 100 lines. The rest of lines should remain in place. There is only one column of words. How can I do this using unix commands?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(head -100 mywords|sort;tail -n +101 mywords) > mywords.100sorted
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(awk 'NR<=100' test.txt | sort;awk 'NR > 100' test.txt) > answer.txt
```

NR means line count

awk is very powerful,it provides many built in variable to solve related problems.

Examples:

FS     regular expression used to separate fields; also settable by option -Ffs.

NF     number of fields in the current record

NR     ordinal number of the current record

FNR    ordinal number of the current record in the current file

FILENAME              the name of the current input file

RS     input record separator (default newline)

OFS    output field separator (default blank)

ORS    output record separator (default newline)

Reference: man awk